# automatically pass the column headers of a dataframe into one column with the corresponding values as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe of averages, [see data frame image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnmQL.png)

id like to have two columns -  one column with headers and another with corresponding values .

I need to repeat this accoss multple dataframes and produce a chart for each. And because the sample data changes i need to be automated..  basically suck it into a dataframe and chart it with minimal coding..
since the values are coming from a dictionary  it seems I can make a column with the first half of the data pair and another column with the second half of the data pair

any ideas on how to efficiently do this with a for loop?

The data frame

```
# Store the Average 
    bbc_avg = {
    "Outlet": target_user,
    "BBC_Compound": np.mean(compound_list),
    "BBC_Positive": np.mean(positive_list),
    "BBC_Neutral": np.mean(neutral_list),
    "BBC_Negative": np.mean(negative_list)
    }

    #columnheaders_to_row
    bbc_avg = { 'Outlet': ["{Outlet}_Compound","{Outlet}_Negative"," 
    {Outlet}_Neutral","{Outlet}_Positive"],
    "Avg_{Outlet}_Values: [
    np.mean(compound_list), 
    np.mean(negative_list),
    np.mean(neutral_list),
    np.mean(positive_list)]}

    bbc_avg
outputs:
    {'Outlet': ['{Outlet}_Compound',
    '{Outlet}_Negative',
    '{Outlet}_Neutral',
    '{Outlet}_Positive'],
    'Avg_{Outlet}_Values': [-0.23009999999999997,
    0.15048000000000003,
    0.7917200000000001,
    0.05779000000000001]}
```

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to SO, it sees you are relatively new here. For better results and to enable to community to better guide you on your questions, please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how you can frame your questions. :)

Comment: Thank you Bernard...  I am learning as I go.  I will review this and think more clearly about things.  Try and map it out.  Half the time I find myself answering my own questions... So before I post I will try to keep that in mind and develop a discipline of better communication

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to transpose, which is relatively easy.

```
bbc_avg.T
```

Comment: that is so slick... yes its just a matrix operation and this is perfect... ill give it a try

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-5fae01ae1fd9> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 df1_transposed = bbc_avg.transpose()
      3 df1_transposed

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'transpose'

Comment: It needs to be applied on your dataframe, not the dictionary. Can you post your code building the frame or an example of it?